# CSS issue on pseudo classes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply this rule to one ID how can I do it

this exist in the CSS and it works fine but I want to overwrite this rule just for one ID 
`#menu-item-3091`  (which is an "li" tag with a tag "a" within it) 
I want to leave this one

```
.sf-menu li:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active{
    background:rgb(243,80,128);
    outline:0;
    color:#999;
}
```

I tried to modify with this code but I don't understand why it doesn't work can you explain it please, where I am wrong

```
.sf-menu #menu-item-3091:hover, .sf-menu #menu-item-3091.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active{
    background:rgb(243,80,128) !important;
    outline:0;
    color:#999;
}
```

this is the html

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
<li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55"><a href="http://www.example.com/contacts/">Contacts</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3091" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3091"><a href="http://shop.example.com">Shop Online</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The second set of css doesn't have any changes..

Comment: Yep, can you explain us what you really want because you wrote the same thing twice.

Comment: It's working for me. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FLaMV/)

Comment: both styling are the same

Comment: Sorry guys may be that's why I am wrong, because I want that in all my li the background has to change color just with the id #menu-item-3091, now I'll try the code suggested, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Assuming you are trying to change the `a` style properties, this will target the `a` only within the `#menu-item-3091` `li` element.

```
.sf-menu #menu-item-3091:hover, .sf-menu #menu-item-3091.sfHover,
.sf-menu #menu-item-3091 a:focus, .sf-menu #menu-item-3091 a:hover, .sf-menu #menu-item-3091 a:active{
    background:rgb(243,80,128) !important;
    outline:0;
    color:#999;
}
```

Comment: Ennui than you very much indeed you read my mind, and I learnt how it works too finally, I found CSS the most difficult language, but I will improve my knoledge thank you again, I added !important to the color as well in order to overwrite the original one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

i have removed other selectors and only used selector for the particular id and only a tag

```
    #menu-item-3091 a:hover,  #menu-item-3091.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:active{
    background:rgb(243,80,128) !important;
    outline:0;
    color:#999;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CfEcz/1/)

Comment: i have removed other selectors and only used selector for the particular id and only a tag